# LinearLayout gravity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm having problems with my xml layout.
I want to make my layout using xml that "simplemessage" would stick to the top, and "textchange" would be filled and centered in the middle of the screen while "hiraganaconfbutton" would stick at the bottom, i tried gravity and centering but for some reason it's not working

Thank you in advance for your help

This is my xml layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simplemessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/guess"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textchange"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="392dp"
            android:text="@string/a"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hiraganaconfbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/confirm" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can it be in relative layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it be like that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/simplemessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/guess"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/simplemessage"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hiraganaconfbutton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textchange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/a"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiraganaconfbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"            
              >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/simplemessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/guess"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/simplemessage"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hiraganaconfbutton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textchange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/a"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/hiraganaconfbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```